# Problem with AuthSubSessionToken PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-contacts-api, authsub

if I try to get a Session Token from google the server doesn't respond..
The code that I use is this:

```
  $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(  
    'Authorization: AuthSub token="' . trim($token) . '"'  
  )); 

  $result = curl_exec($ch);  
  curl_close($ch);  

  $splitStr = split("=", $result);  

  return trim($splitStr[1]);
```

but the server doesn't respond..No error code..nothing of nothing.. :(
The token that I take from https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest is correct because I can use it as Single-use token..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check - have you checked your apache error logs? /var/log/httpd (or apache2) on linux?

Make sure full error reporting is on too! Drop this at the top of the page

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

EDIT:

Also try this:

```
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
```

just before curl_close()

Comment: There aren't errors :(
The $splitStr is empty and I think that is because the server doesn't respond..There is a library like CURL that I can use to contact the server of google?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you figured it out, the problem is that you should request the first token using session=1, if you use session=0 the request won't work (mine was failing with 403)